# Why integral closure of $F[x,y,z]/(x^2-y^2z)$ is $F[\frac{\bar x}{\bar y},\bar y]$?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R=F[x,y,z]/(x^2-y^2z)$. I'm trying to determine the integral closure of $R$. I know that $R$ is an integral domain (since $x^2-y^2z$ is irreducible over $F[y,z]$). Now, I know that $$0=\overline{x^2-y^2z}=\bar x^2-\bar y^2\bar z\implies \left(\frac{\bar x}{\bar y}\right)^2=\bar z.$$
Since $\bar z$ is integral, then so is $\frac{\bar x}{\bar y}$.

**Q1) Why is $\bar z$ integral ? is it because $\bar x^2-\bar y^2\bar z=0$ and that $f(t)=\bar x^2-\bar y^2 t\in R[t] ?$**

Let $S$ be the integral closure of $R$. Then $S\supset F[\frac{\bar x}{\bar y},\bar y ]$.

**Q2) Why $S\supset F[\frac{\bar x}{\bar y},\bar y ]$ ? Where does it come from ? To me it would be $S\supset F[\bar x,\bar y,\bar z]$, but I also don't know why... just intuition.**

For the other inclusion, do we have that for an integral domain $R$, if $S$ is the integral closure, then $S\subset Frac(R)$ ? If yes, then,$$F[\frac{\bar x}{\bar y},\bar y]\subset S\subset Frac(F[\frac{\bar x}{\bar y},\bar y])=F(\frac{\bar x}{\bar y},\bar y),$$
and since in general $R$ is the biggest ring in $Frac(R)$, we have necessarily that $S=R$, i.e. $S=F[\frac{\bar x}{\bar y},\bar y]$.

**Q3) I'm really not sure about my last argument... is it really true ? And if yes, why ?**

Comment: 1) In fact, $\bar z\in R$; 2) Since the generators $\bar x/\bar y$ and $\bar y$ are integral over $R$; 3) Of course $S\subseteq Q(R)$, by definition. But $R$ is not the biggest ring in $Q(R)$. For instance, $\mathbb Z\subsetneq\mathbb Z[\frac 12]\subseteq\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Let me show you what's going on for $R=F[st,s,t^2]$ (btw, your ring is isomorphic to this one): we have $R\subset S=F[s,t]$, $Q(R)=Q(S)=F(s,t)$, and $R\subset S$ is an integral extension since $s,t$, the generators of $S$, are integral over $R$. Then one can immediately conclude that the integral closure of $R$ is $S$.

Comment: Notice that Q2) is answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2119160)

Comment: This was answered late, but now this is answered :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Q1)**

Notice that we should avoid saying "an element is integral". We should say "an element is integral **over this ring**". Here $\bar z$ is not only integral over $R$, but actually *belongs* to $R$.

Then $\dfrac{\bar x}{\bar y}$ is a root of the *monic* polynomial $T^2-\bar z \in R[T]$, showing that $\dfrac{\bar x}{\bar y}$ is integral over $R$.

### **Q2)**

Answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2119207).

### **Q3)**

I agree that $S \subset \mathrm{Frac}\left( F\left[\bar y,\frac{\bar x}{\bar y} \right] \right)$ (see the previous link), but in order to conclude $S=F[\frac{\bar x}{\bar y},\bar y]$, I don't understand your argument (e.g. what is "biggest ring" supposed to mean?).

[
By the way, $F\left[\bar y,\frac{\bar x}{\bar y} \right]$ is larger that $R$ ! If $\frac{\bar x}{\bar y}$ was an element $\bar P$ of $R$, then
$$x-yP(x,y,z) = Q(x,y,z)\cdot (x^2-y^2z)$$ for some $P,Q \in F[x,y,z]$.
There are several ways to show that this equation can't hold, for instance taking the derivative w.r.t $x$ ! You get $1-yP_x = (x^2-y^2z)Q_x + 2xQ$, the LHS is $1$ at $(0,0,0)$ but thr RHS is $0$ at $(0,0,0)$.
]

Anyway, how do we find the integral closure of $R$ in $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ ?
Here is a little lemma:

> If $R$ is an integral domain and $R \subset S \subset \mathrm{Frac}(R)$ is a subring, such that
>
> - $S$ is integral over $R$
> - $\mathrm{Frac}(R)=\mathrm{Frac}(S)$
> - $S$ is integrally closed (e.g. a UFD)
>
> then $S$ is the integral closure of $R$ in $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$.

In our case, let $S = F\left[\bar y,\frac{\bar x}{\bar y} \right]$. It is integral over $R$ (see Q1) above).
You also showed that $\mathrm{Frac}(R)=\mathrm{Frac}(S)$ (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2119207)).
Finally, $\bar y$ and $\frac{\bar x}{\bar y}$ are [algebraically independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108698) over $F$, so that $S \cong F[X,Y]$, which is a UFD.

Therefore, by the lemma, $S$ is the integral closure of $R$ in $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$.

[
There are several ways to show algebraic independence here. For instance, if $\bar y$ and $\frac{\bar x}{\bar y}$ were algebraically dependent, then as $\mathrm{Frac}(R) = \mathrm{Frac}(S)$, we would have
$$\mathrm{tr\, deg}_F(\mathrm{Frac}(R))<2,$$
which implies in particular that $\bar x$ and $\bar y$ satisfy a polynomial relation which can be lifted to
$ P(x,y) \in (x^2-y^2z) $
which is only possible if $P = 0 \in F[x,y]$.
]

$
\tag*{$\color{green}\checkmark$}
$

---

Here are some hints for proving the lemma. Let $Q$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$. We have $S \subset Q$ because $S \subset \mathrm{Frac}(R)$ and $R \subset S$ is integral.
We have $Q \subset S$ because of the two other hypothesis and because $R \subset S$.